# wpf vb.net Custom Control AddHandler not firing

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, custom-controls

I am trying to make a custom control that is based on the textbox control. This textbox control contains a button, listbox, and popup as well. I try to add an event handler to the button's mouse down event in the OnApplyTemplate function of the class.  When I step through debugging, the OnApplyTemplate is called and the event handler code is added.

**My problem** is that when I click the button the event handler sub DropDownButton_MouseDown is not called.

here is my class:

```
Imports System.Windows.Controls.Primitives

<TemplatePart(Name:="PART_ControlBorder", Type:=GetType(Border))> _
<TemplatePart(Name:="PART_DropDownButton", Type:=GetType(Button))> _
<TemplatePart(Name:="PART_Popup", Type:=GetType(Popup))> _
<TemplatePart(Name:="PART_ListBox", Type:=GetType(ListBox))> _

Public Class AutoCompleteTextBox
    Inherits TextBox

#Region "DECLARATIONS"
    Private Mainborder As Border
    Private popup As Popup
    Private listBox As ListBox
    Private dropDownButton As Button

#End Region

#Region "METHODS"
    Private Sub PopupOpen()
        If popup IsNot Nothing And popup.IsOpen = False Then
            popup.IsOpen = True
        Else
            Return
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DropDownButton_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        PopupOpen()
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "APPLY TEMPLATE"
    Public Overrides Sub OnApplyTemplate()
        MyBase.OnApplyTemplate()

        If Me.Template IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim button__1 As Button = TryCast(Me.Template.FindName("PART_DropDownButton", Me), Button)
            If button__1 IsNot dropDownButton Then
                'First unhook existing handler
                If dropDownButton IsNot Nothing Then
                    RemoveHandler dropDownButton.MouseDown, AddressOf DropDownButton_MouseDown
                End If
                dropDownButton = button__1
                If dropDownButton IsNot Nothing Then
                    AddHandler dropDownButton.MouseDown, AddressOf DropDownButton_MouseDown
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "CONSTRUCTOR"
    Sub New()
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(GetType(AutoCompleteTextBox), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(GetType(AutoCompleteTextBox)))
    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

I am using wpf .net 4.5 in visual studio 2012.  Here is my xaml for the custom control called AutoCompleteTextBox, the control is defined in another project within the solution:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:krisis="clr-namespace:Krisis.Controls;assembly=Krisis.Controls"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <krisis:AutoCompleteTextBox SearchText="Bob" Width="200" MinHeight="35" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Can someone please help me wire up this event handler so that when I click the button the sub DropDownButton_MouseDown is called.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I CHanged the OnApplyTemplate to the following and it now works:

```
Public Overrides Sub OnApplyTemplate()
    MyBase.OnApplyTemplate()

    '' if template is not nothing then initialize controls and wire up the event handlers
    If Me.Template IsNot Nothing Then

        InitializePopup()
        InitializeBorder()

        ''reset the handler for DropDownButton
        If DropDownButton IsNot Nothing Then
            RemoveHandler DropDownButton.Click, AddressOf DropDownButton_Click
        End If
        InitializeButton()
        If DropDownButton IsNot Nothing Then
            AddHandler DropDownButton.Click, AddressOf DropDownButton_Click
        End If

        ''reset handlers for listbox
        If ResultsListBox IsNot Nothing Then
            RemoveHandler ResultsListBox.PreviewMouseDown, AddressOf ResultListBox_PreviewMouseDown
            RemoveHandler ResultsListBox.KeyDown, AddressOf ResultListBox_KeyDown
        End If
        InitializeListbox()
        If ResultsListBox IsNot Nothing Then
            AddHandler ResultsListBox.PreviewMouseDown, AddressOf ResultListBox_PreviewMouseDown
            AddHandler ResultsListBox.KeyDown, AddressOf ResultListBox_KeyDown
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

here is an example of the INitializeControl sub i wrote that is used above:

```
Private Sub InitializeButton()
    If dropDownButton Is Nothing Then
        dropDownButton = TryCast(Me.Template.FindName("PART_DropDownButton", Me), Button)
    End If
End Sub
```